# (Why) Were animals expelled from Eden?

Tags: animals, parashat-bereishit, gan-eden

> And the LORD God formed out of the earth all the wild beasts and all the birds of the sky, and brought them to the man (in Eden). [Genesis.2.19](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Genesis.2.19?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)

I'm confused about what happened to the animal: God formed them somewhere, brought them to Adam in Eden to be named, then Adam is expelled from Eden and I don't know the fate of the animals.

Were they expelled also? If yes, why? If to serve man - only a slight portion of animals are actually of any use? Were some left in Eden for our afterdeath experiences?